# java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType and java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark Data Frames to query Cassandra, do some processing and store the results back to Cassandra. I am using Datastax Enterprise 4.8.3 and doing a spark submit. I get the following error, but not every time.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType$; unable to create instance
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1788)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor89.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:967)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1785)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.tail(List.scala:339)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.tail(List.scala:334)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.popPhase(SymbolTable.scala:172)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.typeParams(Symbols.scala:1489)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoArgsTypeRef.typeParams(Types.scala:2144)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.initializedTypeParams(Types.scala:2408)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.typeParamsMatchArgs(Types.scala:2409)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$AliasTypeRef$class.dealias(Types.scala:2232)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$3.dealias(Types.scala:2539)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.typeToJavaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:1259)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:202)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.AtomicType.<init>(DataType.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType.<init>(TimestampType.scala:37)
    ... 113 more
```

If i am getting the SQL timestamp error, I should be getting that for all the rows that I am trying to insert. But this happens randomly and sometimes it does not happen at all.

Am using the following configuration:

```
version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.3.1" % "provided"
)
```

I could see that the below error was coming for scala 2.10.x versions and it has been resolved in 2.11.x versions.

Causedby: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list
But I am restricted to use scala 2.10 because the Datastax Enterprise latest version uses the same. Also, why do I get the below error ? Also, I do not get this error every time. Sometimes it pops up out of the blue and other times it does not occur at all. The executor task fails midway as

[Stage 18:=============================> (109 + 8) / 200]ERROR 2016-01-27 09:43:16 org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 105.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 519)

java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType$; unable to create instance
Any help/ info would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

DSE 4.8.3 uses Spark 1.4 not 1.3. If you build against 1.4 this may fix the conversion issue.

Comment: Building against 1.4.1 did not resolve the issue. Still getting the same error sometimes. Like for example 3 times in 10 runs

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Looking at this more, and working through the code, it appears it is just that reflection is not thread safe in scala-2.10 http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html as this error happens on write to saveToCassandra only. I would say you're left with 2 options:

1) Writing out via foreachPartition and not relying on saveToCassandra 
2) Better still, just letting Spark do what Spark does and allow it to retry the task and complete the job anyway.

*Original:
Actually reading that more closely
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list
I'm thinking that maybe just empty data and your doing an op on an empty dataset.
[Is it valid to reduce on an empty set of sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986241/is-it-valid-to-reduce-on-an-empty-set-of-sets)*