# Cosine similarity of two sparse vectors in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe with two columns where each row has a Sparse Vector. I try to find a proper way to calculate the cosine similarity (or just the dot product) of the two vectors in each row.

However, I haven't been able to find any library or tutorial to do it for Sparse vectors.

The only way I found is the following:

1. Create a k X n matrix, where n items are described as k-dimensioned vectors. For representing each item as a k dimension vector, you can use ALS which represents each entity in a latent factor space. The dimension of this space (k) can be chosen by you. This k X n matrix can be represented as RDD[Vector].
2. Convert this k X n matrix to RowMatrix.
3. Use columnSimilarities() function to get a n X n matrix of similarities between n items.

I feel it is an overkill to calculate all the cosine similarities for each pair while I need it only for the specific pairs in my (quite big) dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

In `Spark 3` there is now method `dot` for a `SparseVector` object, which takes another vector as its argument.

If you want to do this in earlier versions, you could create a user defined function that follows this algorithm:

- Take intersection of your vectors' indices.
- Get two subarrays of your vectors' values based on the indices from the intersection.
- Do pairwise multiplication of the elements of those two subarrays.
- Sum the values resulting values from such pairwise multiplication.

Here's my realization of it:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector

def dotProduct(vec: SparseVector, vecOther: SparseVector) = {
    val commonIndices = vec.indices intersect vecOther.indices
    commonIndices.map(x => vec(x) * vecOther(x)).reduce(_+_)
}
```

I guess you know how to turn it into a `Spark` `UDF` from here and apply it to your dataframe's columns.

And if you normalize your sparse vectors with `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Normalizer` before computing your dot product, you'll get cosine similarity in the end (by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition)).

Answer (score 1):

Great answer above @Sergey-Zakharov +1.
A few adds-on:

1. The reduce [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986241/is-it-valid-to-reduce-on-an-empty-set-of-sets) work on empty sequences.
2. Make sure computing L2 normalization.

```
val normalizer = new Normalizer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("normFeatures")
  .setP(2.0)

val l2NormData = normalizer.transform(df_features)
```

and

```
val dotProduct = udf {(v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector) =>
    v1.indices.intersect(v2.indices).map(x => v1(x) * v2(x)).reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse(0.0)
}
```

and then

```
val df = dfA.crossJoin(broadcast(dfB))
    .withColumn("dot", dotProduct(col("featuresA"), col("featuresB")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of vectors you want to calculate the dot product with is small, cache the RDD[Vector] table.  Create a new table `[cosine_vectors]` that is a filter on the original table to only select the vectors you want the cosine similarities for. Broadcast join those two together and calculate.